# Make Strings In List Uppercase - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, uppercase

I'm in the process of learning python and with a practical example I've come across a problem I cant seem to find the solution for.
The error I get with the following code is 
`'list' object has to attribute 'upper'`.

```
def to_upper(oldList):
    newList = []
    newList.append(oldList.upper())

words = ['stone', 'cloud', 'dream', 'sky']
words2 = (to_upper(words))
print (words2)
```

Comment: as you can tell by the different answers there are many ways to do this. Here's just another way, replace the last line in your `to_upper` function with these two lines `newList.extend([o.upper() for o in oldList]);
    return newList`

Answer (score 6):

Since the `upper()` method is defined for string only and not for list, you should iterate over the list and uppercase each string in the list like this:

```
def to_upper(oldList):
    newList = []
    for element in oldList:
        newList.append(element.upper())
    return newList
```

This will solve the issue with your code, however there are shorter/more compact version if you want to capitalize an array of string.

- **map** function `map(f, iterable)`. In this case your code will look like this:

  ```
  words = ['stone', 'cloud', 'dream', 'sky']
  words2 = list(map(str.upper, words))
  print (words2)
  ```
- **List comprehension** `[func(i) for i in iterable]`.In this case your code will look like this:

  ```
  words = ['stone', 'cloud', 'dream', 'sky']
  words2 = [w.upper() for w in words]
  print (words2)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *list comprehension* notation and apply the`upper` method to each string in `words`:

```
words = ['stone', 'cloud', 'dream', 'sky']
words2 = [w.upper() for w in words]
```

Or alternatively use `map` to apply the function:

```
words2 = list(map(str.upper, words))
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `upper()` method is implemented for strings only. You have to call it from each child of the list, and not from the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you're learning Python! In your example, you are trying to uppercase a list. If you think about it, that simply can't work. You have to uppercase the *elements* of that list. Additionally, you are only going to get an output from your function if you return a result at the end of the function. See the code below.

Happy learning!

```
 def to_upper(oldList):
        newList = []
        for l in oldList:
          newList.append(l.upper())
        return newList

    words = ['stone', 'cloud', 'dream', 'sky']
    words2 = (to_upper(words))
    print (words2)
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/JsnB/1)

Comment: The other answers are correct as well, but I hope my explanations are helpful for you to get a better hold of Python as you explore.